# How to make Organization Based GitHub Tokens?

Tags: github, github-actions

Why am I only allowed to create personal tokens....? This seems to be a huge flaw in their system... Is there any way to create an organizational based token, so if specific actors of the company come-and-go we don't need to constantly create new tokens & potentially have production pipelines stop working?

On the inverse... creating a personal token that needs access to FULL private repo's to work on behalf of the organization is a huge flaw in personal IP... This seems ridiculous so it can't be the truth... please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to create a token directly at the organization level (yet?).

However, you can **create a separate github account**, and add it to the organization **owners team**.

Then, you can get and use **this account personnal access token** as you wish inside the organization (it will be like an organization exclusive account).

*Note that if you do it this way, the token will also have admin access to this specific account repositories, but that may be not be a problem here. But be careful to not add this account to another organization as well, otherwise using the PAT will allow access to both organizations.*